# Can I assign a language for each iMessage contact?

Tags: ios, messages, internationalization, auto-complete

I write iMessages in different languages, depending on who the message goes to. Text input is very difficult if auto-completion/correction is using the wrong dictionary. Is there a way to assign a language for my contacts, so that iMessage will pick that up? Or if not, is there at least a quick way (without leaving the app) to switch languages manually?

Comment: I asked Apple for this feature through [their feedback form](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) 4 years ago. Still I have to tap the globe practically every time I write a message on my stupidphone. Especially strange for this multinational company to expect users to monolingual. I am switching between three languages all the time, why can't my 'smartphone'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think automatic switching is available at the moment but a quick way to switch manually without leaving the app is to enable multiple keyboards. You can do this is Settings -> General -> Keyboards. 
Your keyboards will now have a globe button next to the 123 button to enable fast switching by tapping the globe and you can hold it down and select the desired language :)
Having the keyboard in a different should change the dictionary and autocorrect features automatically.

Hope this helps